# Why can't I find my label text using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementPerPayPeriodTxt]").blur(function (evt) {
try {
    val1 = (this.value);
    alert(val1);
    val2 = $("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]");
    alert(val2.value);
}
catch (e) { }
});
```

I have them selected by wildcard because it's within a master page. val1 works just fine (textbox), but val2 (label) never gets what I need. I've also tried val2.text, val2.val, valueOf(val2), val2.html, val2.attr('text'). I either get Object [object], undefined, or some long function string.

```
<asp:Label ID="HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt" runat="server">
```

if it helps, I am setting the text of this label in the codebehind

Comment: is this a `ClientID` problem?

Comment: I don't think so? I'm not sure how that works exactly, but if I'm working with the textbox just fine then why would the label be acting up? They're right next to eachother.

Comment: `val2` is being set to the array of all objects having an ID that ends with `HealthCareReimbursementPerPayPeriodTxt`, but the `<asp:Label>` you included has an ID (`HealthCareReimbursementTotalLbl`) that doesn't match the selector

Comment: @jimmym715 sorry, that was an error in my question, I have fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `val2.html` or `val2.text` should work. `.val` only works for inputs and other controls that hold values such as HiddenFields, not for controls that are just converted to HTML elements like Labels.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to change this

```
val2 = $("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]");
```

by

```
val2 = $("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]")[0];
```

A jQuery selector doesn't return a DOM object directly. You could also use a class selector

```
<asp:Label ID="HealthCareReimbursementTotalLbl" Text="0.00" runat="server" 
    CssClass="healthCareReimbursementTotalLbl"></asp:Label>
```

And then you could do

```
$(function(){
    $(".healthCareReimbursementTotalTxt").blur(function (evt) {
    try {
        val1 = (this.value);
        alert(val1);
        val2 = $(".healthCareReimbursementTotalLbl")[0];
        alert(val2.value);
    }
    catch (e) { }
    });
});
```

Comment: this does not work. It is still getting all the same results which leads me to believe that it is finding the label just fine.

Comment: you need to use `val2[0].value` instead of `val2.value`

Comment: Is this js code within document ready handler or at least defined AFTER the label definition?

Comment: I think it must be, or else why would it be getting my textbox? They are right next to eachother.

Comment: explore the html with firebug or any other browser plugin and check if the label has the class `healthCareReimbursementTotalLbl`. This code is pretty standard so probably there is something you're not telling me.

Comment: I'm using IE so it becomes a span

Comment: <span id="MainContent_HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt" sab="151">
Text - 24

Comment: Are you trying to handle the blur event of your txt (HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt)  and explore the label value (HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsLbl)?

Comment: When I blur my txt, I am trying to multiply the txt and the label values together. everything I am doing is in my function from above

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
val2 = $("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]")[0].val();
```

Comment: how bout `alert(val2.text());` ?

Answer (score 0):

You said the label is getting changed into a `<span></span>`, which wouldn't have a `val` property.  I think you need to use `.html()` since you need the text *between* the tags.

i.e

`val2 = $("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]").html();`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementPerPayPeriodTxt]").blur(function (evt) {
              try {
                  val1 = (this.value);
                  alert(val1);

                  // first try wether your are getting this elemnt or not 
                  alert($("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]").length);
                  if ($("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]").length > 0) {
                      alert("item found");
                      val2 = $("[id$=HealthCareReimbursementNumPayPeriodsTxt]");
                      alert(val2.val());
                      // if it does not work try
                     // alert(val2.html()); or alert(val2.text);
                  }
                  else {
                      alert("item not found");
                  }
              }
              catch (e) { }
          });
```